# How to deny access only one area in .net MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, authorize-attribute

I'm trying to deny only one area using .Net MVC 4 and I'm not getting results. What happens is when I put `<authentication mode="Forms" />` in web.config everything is denied: all the site and is not what I want, I only want to deny the admin area.

I put the `AuthorizeAttribute` in `BaseController` of my Admin area, still not working:

```
   public class AutenticarAdminAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/admin/login");
            }
        }
    }
```

Global.asax: `filters.Add(new AutenticarAdminAttribute());`

If I remove `<authentication mode="Forms" />` from web.config the `AuthorizeAttribute` do not do the work, `IsAuthenticated` is always true.

And when I put again `<authentication mode="Forms" />` in web.config everything is denied.

I'm not able to restrict only a area, how do?

BaseController in Admin Area:

```
[AutenticarAdmin]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseController()
    {
    }
}
```

DefaultAdminController in Admin Area:

```
public class DefaultController : BaseController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Public Controller:

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `filters.Add(new AutenticarAdminAttribute());` from your global.asax. Registering global filter it will be the same as put the Attribute in all controllers of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding OnAuthorization method and inside checking if user is IsAuthenticated.

Authorisation and Authentication are 2 different things !

With regards to authentication, you can set default redirect url and login url in .config file (in authentication tag).

Hope that helps.

Comment: How I can allow authentication only and one area in .Net MVC? What I read say to not use <location> tag in web.config for MVC applications. Use AuthorizeAttribute instead.

Comment: When I use default redirect url and login url in .config file the problems still: everything is denied. I'm not want everything dinied, only admin area.

Comment: That's correct - location tag was fine in asp.net but MVC gives you attributes for that. With regards to your question - authorization determines if user has access to content (based on roles) - it checks if user has a specific role assigned.

Comment: when you use authorize attrbute you have to pass role name. in your scenario, role name would be "admin" or something like that. roles are being assigned to current principal when you authenticate. have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: yes, you have to add role to the user - IPrincipal needs to know what are the user roles. Then on Authorize attribute you pass that role name.

Comment: still not working :(, a blank page now opens and IsAuthenticate is always true :(.

Comment: don't use your AutenticarAdminAttribute as it does not do anything. Instead use AuthorizeAttribute on method or controller and pass role name to the attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]. IsAuthenticated will always be true if the user is authenticated.

Comment: That's the problem. The user is not authenticate and IsAuthenticate is always true. If I put the <authentication mode="Forms" /> in web.config always is denied, not only the area I want.

Comment: what authentication mechanism do you use ? if it's microsoft membership provider, then make sure user has roles assigned. also where did you add Authorize attribute ?

Comment: have a look at nerddinner example. it's really well explained http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part9.htm

Comment: I'm using Forms Authentication, see my question, it's have all what i'm using. The problem is <authentication mode="Forms" /> is not working like I want.

Comment: ok, add the Authorize attribute to your admin controller and let me know what's happening.

Comment: I add. If I not have <authentication mode="Forms" /> in config file, nothing is denied. If I put <authentication mode="Forms" /> everything is denied.

Comment: Sorry for asking again the same question, but did you add Authorize attribute to admin controller or to base controller (as stated in your post). Also what do you mean by "base controller" ?

Comment: I put in BaseController and inherit in all controllers that need authentication.

Comment: Can you paste the definition of base controller, admin controller and 1 other controller which does not require authentication? otherwise it's very hard to "guess" what's happening in your application. Authentication mechanism works very well, if used properly.

Comment: that would mean that your authentication does not work. how do you authenticate user? do you use Membership to do that? or do you create Authentication ticket manually?